# Framer motion slows down at keyframes

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am creating a react application and using framer motion for animation, I am trying to circulate a box around a central axis so it the spinning motion may look 3d. I am defining key frames so for example if I want to move the box on axis I use
`{ x: [0, -100, 0, 100, 0] }`
The problem is that circular motion needs to be smooth and consistent, but framer motion slows down animation at every keyframe, which doesn't create the effect I want.
So is there any way I can disable this slow down ?

Comment: did you fix this yet?

Answer (score 0):

In the `animate` prop add a `transition: {ease: "linear"}`

It will look like this

```
<motion.div
  animate={{
    x: [0, -100, 0, 100, 0],
    transition: {
      ease: "linear",
    }
  }}
></motion.div>
```